# How to convert a list of dictionaries to a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How to convert a list of dictionaries to a list?

Here is what I have:

```
{
    "sources": [
        {
            "ID": "6953",
            "VALUE": "https://address-jbr.ofp.ae"
        },
        {
            "ID": "6967",
            "VALUE": "https://plots.ae"
        },
        {
            "ID": "6970",
            "VALUE": "https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae"
        }]}
```

Here is what I want it to look like:

```
({'6953':'https://address-jbr.ofp.ae','6967':'https://plots.ae','6970':'https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae'})
```

Comment: what have you tried ? this seems fairly  straightforward? is ther an issue you are facing ?

Comment: I have no idea what to try

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed very straightforward:

```py
data = {
    "sources": [
        {
            "ID": "6953",
            "VALUE": "https://address-jbr.ofp.ae"
        },
        {
            "ID": "6967",
            "VALUE": "https://plots.ae"
        },
        {
            "ID": "6970",
            "VALUE": "https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae"
        }]
}
```

Then:

```py
data_list = [{x["ID"]: x["VALUE"]} for x in data["sources"]]
```

Which is the same as:

```py
data_list = []
for x in data["sources"]:
    data_list.append({
        x["ID"]: x["VALUE"]
    })
```

EDIT: You said convert to a "list" in the question and that confused me. Then this is what you want:

```
data_dict = {x["ID"]: x["VALUE"] for x in data["sources"]}
```

Which is the same as:

```
data_dict = {}
for x in data["sources"]:
    data_dict[x["ID"]] = x["VALUE"]
```

P.S. Seems like you're asking for answers to your course assignments or something here, which is not what this place is for.

Comment: Thanks, but still I didn't get what I wanted, 
I wanted it to look like this:
({'6953':'https://address-jbr.ofp.ae','6967':'https://plots.ae','6970':'https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae'})
However, I got this:
({'6953':'https://address-jbr.ofp.ae'},{'6967':'https://plots.ae'},{'6970':'https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae'})

Comment: I edited the code. You said convert to a list in the question. That's not a list that you want though! That's dict, which for some reason is inside a tuple. If being inside a tuple is necessary then just do: `(data_dict)`

Comment: Did the edited code solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

A solution using pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "sources": [
        {"ID": "6953", "VALUE": "https://address-jbr.ofp.ae"},
        {"ID": "6967", "VALUE": "https://plots.ae"},
        {"ID": "6970", "VALUE": "https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae"},
    ]
}

a = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["sources"])
print(a.set_index("ID").T.to_dict(orient="records"))
```

outputs to:

```
[{'6953': 'https://address-jbr.ofp.ae', '6967': 'https://plots.ae', '6970': 'https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
Dict = {
    "sources": [
        {
            "ID": "6953",
            "VALUE": "https://address-jbr.ofp.ae"
        },
        {
            "ID": "6967",
            "VALUE": "https://plots.ae"
        },
        {
            "ID": "6970",
            "VALUE": "https://dubai-creek-harbour.ofp.ae"
        }]}

# Store all the keys here
value_LIST = []
for item_of_list in Dict["sources"]:
    for key, value in item_of_list.items():
        value_LIST.append(value)
```